# {{ language }} variable not available in block template

Tags: 8, theming, i18n-l10n

We are trying to generate a language dependent link in a custom block we created though the UI and placed it into a region.

If I `{{ dump(language) }}` in `page.html.twig`, I've got it there. But not in the block. Is this by design? Where/How can I get access to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this with a preprocess hook:

```
mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
  $variables['language'] = $language;
}
```

The `language` variable will then be available in your block template as it is in the page one.